# Going through oauth2 not getting back a refresh token but getting back id token

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I have an app that connects doctors with aptients.

I'm making an OAUTH request to google.

```
            const {tokens} = await oauth2Client.getToken(request.query.code);
            oauth2Client.setCredentials({
                access_token: tokens.access_token,
            });

            let {data} = await oauth2.userinfo.get({
                auth: oauth2Client,
            });
```

it's not returning a refresh token. It returns an id_token but not a refresh token. It returns the access_token, expiry_date, id_token, but no refresh token. I noticed that the scope is scope:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid'
```

I did implement google login on my website. Might it be confusing google login with google authentication to get my calendar information?

Google login is implemented using passportjs..